# How to provide API JSON schema per endpoint?

Tags: json, rest, spring-boot, swagger, schema

I have a Spring Boot application which serves REST API to the users. Now I would like to provide a JSON schema for every endpoint separately.

Example:

- I have an endpoint `/companies` which allows searching in companies by `name`, `size` and `country`. I would like to have an endpoint `/companies/schema` which returns me an automatically generated JSON schema for the `/companies` endpoint.
- I have an endpoint `/employees` which allows searching in employees by `firstName`, `lastName` and `age`. I would like to have an endpoint `/employees/schema` which returns me an automatically generated JSON schema for the `/employees` endpoint.
- and so on

I have Swagger in the application, but AFAIK it can generate JSON schema for all endpoints at one page. I didn't find any option to generate it per each endpoint separately.

Any ideas about how to achieve that in the Spring Boot application?

Comment: By "JSON Schema for each endpoint" do you mean "OpenAPI definition for this specific endpoint" or "[JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org/) for the `company` object / `employee` object / whatever object is returned by this endpoint". Please note that OpenAPI (Swagger) != JSON Schema, but OpenAPI uses an [extended subject](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.2.md#schema-object) of JSON Schema to define data models.

Comment: @Helen do you have solution for either of these options?

Comment: I don't. Just trying to clarify the meaning of your question, because those options are two different things.

Comment: I would rather have something like OpenAPI. Maybe not everything will be needed, but I would like to have an information on how the request should look like and how the basic response is shaped.